# Not able to print variables of content type

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

I want to print variables of a particular content type, but I have not found any way. Here is my code.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node_mytype(&$vars) {   
  echo '<pre>';print_r($vars); echo '</pre>'; 
}
```

This function is in template.php. Is there a problem with my code?

Comment: which version. D7 or D6?

Answer (score 5):

Try this: (D7)

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($vars, true) . '</pre>');
}
```